# u-boot compilation error

Tags: c, compilation, u-boot

I have a feeling this may be too broad of a question but I'm hoping some may be a u-boot expert so I'm going to give it a shot...

When compiling for a powerpc based setup similar to redwood, I'm getting an error: nand.c:91: undefined reference to `board_nand_init'

The function is in ndfc.c, which does not have a .h file, and the prototype is defined in nand.h, I don't understand how a function in ndfc.c can be called by another module.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error is usually caused by not defining all the compilation variables required.

See the [U-Boot README file](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot.git;a=blob_plain;f=README;hb=HEAD).  Some are set with the Makefile:  for example `make TQM823L_config` which defines all the variables normally used for the TQM823L board.

Other configuration settings need to be done by hand editing the header files.